# PhoneGap Build & NativeControls & Local Notification plugin

Tags: plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created a phonegap application using NativeControls plugin (for Tab Bar) as well as local notification plugin using XCode. It works fine with iphone simulator. But as far as phonegap build is concerned, neither tab bar is seen in device nor the local notification is fired. I followed the instructions from https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins and have included both plugins in feature tag in config.xml but in vain. Please help with some tutorial or documentation. I searched a lot but everywhere i found instructions for Childbrowser plugin. is it that nativecontrols or local notification is not compatible with phonegap build and childbrowser is compatible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On that same URL there's a section that states "Supported plugins". The only one right now is Child Browser. So NativeControls and LocalNotification are not supported by PhoneGap Build.

Comment: I guessed it. But is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: You have two choices: 1) Wait until PhoneGap Build releases support for those plugins. 2) Build with XCode

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help. I will update with the things as soon as i can.

Comment: In fact the requirement is to create an application which can be deployed in all devices (iphone, android, blackberry and others). Hence trying with phonegap.